# Чем можно заменить цифру в тексте в innerText?

Tags: javascript

```
new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => {
    const Node = document.querySelector('.myclass');
  if (Node.matches('.myclss') && Node.innerText === 'Cегодня 1 ноября'){
 document.querySelector('.button').classList.remove('disabled'); 
  } else {  
 document.querySelector('.button').classList.add('disabled');
   }}).observe(document, { subtree: true, childList: true });
```

У меня код, который при обнаружении элемента  и определённого текста в нём удаляет или добавляет класс. Код работает, но проблема в том, что текст меняется, а точнее меняется всего лишь цифра в этом тексте  `innerText === 'Cегодня 2 ноября'` и так далее. Я сделал так `if (Node.matches('.myclss') && Node.innerText === 'Cегодня 1 ноября' || Node.innerText === 'Cегодня 2 ноября' || Node.innerText === 'Cегодня 3 ноября')` и так далее. И всё работает. Но код получается грамозкий. Нельзя ли вместо цифры что-то подставить, какой-нибудь универсальный символ `innerText === 'Cегодня * ноября'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться regex `\d+` и немного скорректировать этот участок кода

```
if (Node.matches('.myclss') && /^Cегодня \d+ ноября$/.test(Node.innerText))
```

`\d+` в регулярном выражении означает одну или более цифр.

Comment: Спасибо! А ещё вопрос.  Что-то подобное с буквой можно сделать? Допустим со словом ноябрь на конце мягкий знак, а в родительном подеже буква Я.  Это же как-то наверное тоже решается?

Comment: @Иван, посмотри справку по регулярным выражениям, у них есть много возможностей